# Why am I getting this SQL error? ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

I have been trying to create a table using Oracle SQL, but no matter what I do I get the error **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**. I know I am not missing a parentheses, so this is extremely frustrating. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I tried. I have no idea what's missing.

```
CREATE TABLE PET 
(
    Pet_ID INT (4) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Owner_First CHAR (15) NOT NULL, 
    Owner_Last CHAR (15) NOT NULL, 
    Pet_Name CHAR (15) NOT NULL, 
    Breed CHAR (15),
    Weight DECIMAL (5,2),
    Age INT (2)
);
```

Edit: Each variable is on its own line. Idk why it won't display the way it is typed when I made my post. Anyways, here's a screenshot.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUlHZ.png)

Comment: I dont get any error running the sql as is

Comment: Now you can see my frustration... I've done SQL before so this is super annoying. Can't figure it out.

Comment: You don't assign a size to `int` data type, take those away and it should work.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. So if I want to specify an integer length, I have to use DECIMAL(4,0) to get the same thing?

Comment: You shouldn't store Age anyway. People (and pets) become older each year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date of birth instead.

Comment: What do you mean by specifying integer length?  An integer will hold from a value from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,648.

Comment: @Jonah - yes but `number(4,0)` or just `number(4)` would be more common as it's the native Oracle [numeric data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-9401BC04-81C4-4CD5-99E7-C5E25C83F608). ANSI data type [are allowed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF) though.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks okay; however, the issue could be with data type you've used here .. i.e. INT.. please try using Pet_ID NUMBER(4)